# Extended properties in NLog

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, nlog, asp.net-core-webapi

Layout mentioned in config file is as follows:

```
Timestamp: ${date}${newline}Title: ${event-properties:item=Title}${newline}Message: ${message}${newline}Machine: ${machinename}${newline}${newline}${LayoutFooter}
```

On exception, I want to add two more properties to this layout, which includes `Stack Trace` and `Inner Exception Message`.

I am achieving the above requirement, by modifying the layout pattern to:

```
Timestamp: ${date}${newline}Title: ${event-properties:item=Title}${newline}Message: ${message}${newline}${event-properties:item=StackTrace}${event-properties:item=InnerException}Machine: ${machinename}${newline}${newline}${LayoutFooter}
```

And then through code,

```cs
private static void WriteLog(LogEvent logEvent)
{
    var log = LogManager.GetLogger(logEvent.Logger);
    LogEventInfo logMsg = new LogEventInfo();
    logMsg.Message = logEvent.Message;
    logMsg.Level = logEvent.LogLevel;
    logMsg.Properties.Add("Title", logEvent.Title);
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(logEvent.StackTrace))
    {
        logMsg.Properties.Add("StackTrace", "Stack Trace: " + logEvent.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(logEvent.InnerException))
    {
        logMsg.Properties.Add("InnerException", "Inner Exception: " + logEvent.InnerException + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    log.Log(logMsg);
}
```

By following above approach, if I need to add more extended properties, I need to change config file and code.

In case of single config file, this approach is fine, but in case of multiple config files, it is time consuming.

Is there any way, through which I can add extended properties only by changing code, and no change in config file.

I was able to achieve this functionality, when I was using Microsoft Enterprise Logging library, as it had `ExtendedProperties` property in `LogEntry` class of `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way, through which I can add extended properties only by changing code, and no change in config file.

There is a [`${all-event-properties}` renderer](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/All-Event-Properties-Layout-Renderer) and it has multiple parameters how to render.